# How to align row of images at the center top of the screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have been trying to align some images at the top center of the screen as you would a title but i have no idea how to do it. I have some images and colours i set for the background and then i created some inkwell widgets (not sure if needed), attached my images in there and placed them in a row.
How can i place that row at the top center of the screen to have the 4 images aligned perfectly at the top?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RelationshipPrefences extends StatelessWidget {
  const RelationshipPrefences({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SizedBox(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  colors: [Color(0xFF1F1F1F), Color(0xFF1F1F1F)],
                ),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/topbig.png"),
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/toptop.png'),
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/top.png'),
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/bluetick.png',
                          width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/purplewatch.png',
                          width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/purplewatch.png',
                          width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/purplewatch.png',
                          width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Positioned` widget and wrap your `Row` widget with it. Then you can give `top: 0.0`

```
             Positioned(
              top: 0.0,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/bluetick.png',
                            width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/purplewatch.png',
                            width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/purplewatch.png',
                            width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/purplewatch.png',
                            width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Thank you both, i ended up using Shrijans' answer because i wanted a line in between each image in the row but i did try out your answer too Tryharder and it gets the job done if i just wanted the images

Answer (score 1):

This is a widget tree that contains a `Column` which consists of a `Row` of `Images`. In this case `Expanded` widget will make the `Image` to get as big as possible will allowing all the widget in the `Row` to have the same size. You may copy paste this code in your IDE, it should works fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
//                    Expanded(
//                      child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
//                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/bluetick.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/bluetick.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/bluetick.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/bluetick.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                // the rest of your widget below the image you align
                // Widget here etc
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ), 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```